# Making Visual Studio 2010 Look Like Eclipse?

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, xna

I have been programming in Visual Studio for a while but I really enjoy the layout of Eclipse. I want to be able to have the same color theme as Eclipse has. What I mean by this is that I want my text to be purple like eclipse and my variable names to be blue and in italics. I also would like to keep the first curly brace on the same line as the method.

If you could show me how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Themes: http://studiostyl.es/

Comment: Open an instance of Eclipse in the background. Now, open Visual Studio 2010. Press Alt+F4. Enjoy cake.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `Tools/Options...` menu. For the braces go to `Text Editor/Your language/Formatting/New Lines/New line option for braces`. For the colors go to `Environment/Fonts and Colors` and go nuts :-)

Comment: What is the color purple that eclipse uses?

Comment: Who knows? Go to Eclipse's config and look it up.

Answer (score 0):

`Open Tools -> Options`,

Under tab `Environment -> Fonts and Color`

I don't suggest this approach since it is not that useful. And the setting is bound to user profile, so if you change user profile (run as) or change device (pc), then the setting is reset to default.